# GLU.gluLookAt in Java OpenGL bindings seems to do nothing

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, glu

I've already checked the other questions on this topic and their solutions haven't worked for me. I'm at a bit of a loss. I have the following functions in my GLEventListener implementation.

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable gl) {
    GL2 gl2 = gl.getGL().getGL2();

    gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl2.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU glu = GLU.createGLU(gl2);
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, 1, 0.1f,100.0f);
    gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl2.glLoadIdentity();
    gl2.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl2.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    GLU glu = GLU.createGLU(gl);

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluLookAt(5,  0, 20, 
                  0, 30,  0, 
                  0,  1,  0);

    gl2.glPushMatrix();
    gl2.glClear( GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );                
    gl2.glLoadIdentity();
    gl2.glTranslatef(x, y, z);        
    gl2.glBegin( GL2.GL_QUADS );
        gl2.glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );

        //24 glVertex3f calls & some colour changes go here.
        gl2.glVertex3f(...)

    gl2.glEnd();
    gl2.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glFlush();
}
```

It doesn't matter what values I put into the gluLookAt() matrix, the view doesn't change. I still end up looking at the same face of a cube.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using shaders to draw your cube?

Comment: I'm new to this and don't know what that means. The cube is just 24 glVertex3f() calls and some colour changes between glBegin(quads) and glEnd(). I'll edit my post to show a bit more of my drawing code.

Comment: check out the answer below - I think you have a bug in your drawing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** Responding to the edit in the original question.  Leaving the original text below because people seem to find it to be useful.

I think your problem is in your cube drawing code.  Check the commentary below: the `glLoadIdentity` call is doing exactly what you would expect - forcing the cube to be there in front of you:

```
gl2.glPushMatrix();     
gl2.glClear( GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
/** Try removing the following glLoadIdentity call below.
  * That call was blowing out the MODELVIEW matrix - it's removing your 
  * gluLookAt call and returning to the identity.
  * As a result, the cube will always be right there in front of you.
  */
// gl2.glLoadIdentity();
gl2.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
gl2.glBegin( GL2.GL_QUADS );
gl2.glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 ); //24 glVertex3f calls & some colour changes go here.
gl2.glVertex3f(...)
gl2.glEnd();
gl2.glPopMatrix();
```

Here's a very quick explanation about what the related calls will do.  See the documentation for more information:

```
gl2.glPushMatrix(); // This preserves current MODEL_VIEW matrix so you can get back here.
                    // Think of it as a checkpoint save in a game.
                    // Most of your objects will be wrapped in push and pop.
gl2.glLoadIdentity(); // This erases the MODEL_VIEW and replaces it with an identity.
                      // This un-does your previous gluLookAt call.  You will rarely use
                      // this inside an object (but it's not impossible).
                      // Does not apply here so don't use.
gl2.glTranslatef(x, y, z); // This is what puts your object out in space for you to find
                           // as opposed to putting it at the origin.  Most objects will
                           // have a translate (and likely a rotate as well).
                           // Note that the order of operations matters:
                           // translate and then rotate != rotate and then translate.
// QUAD strip code with vertices and colors - you're okay with these.
gl2.glPopMatrix(); // This brings back the MODEL_VIEW that you originally saved by pushing
                   // it.
```

The great thing about the matrix code in OpenGL is that once you get a portfolio of example code that you understand, you'll always have it as a reference.  When I switched from [IrisGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIS_GL) to OpenGL back in the day, it took me a little while to port my utilities over and then I never looked back.

**ORIGINAL:** You need to add your cube drawing code - if you are putting the cube in the vicinity of (0, 30, 0), it's highly likely that the code is doing what you asked it to.

Checking the OpenGL FAQ, there's a specific question and answer that is likely relevant to what you're doing: [8.080 Why doesn't gluLookAt work?](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm)  I'm going to quote the whole answer as there really isn't a good break but please visit the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/), the answer is likely there:

> This is usually caused by incorrect
>   transformations.
>
> Assuming you are using
>   gluPerspective() on the Projection
>   matrix stack with zNear and zFar as
>   the third and fourth parameters, you
>   need to set gluLookAt on the ModelView
>   matrix stack, and pass parameters so
>   your geometry falls between zNear and
>   zFar.
>
> It's usually best to experiment with a
>   simple piece of code when you're
>   trying to understand viewing
>   transformations. Let's say you are
>   trying to look at a unit sphere
>   centered on the origin. You'll want to
>   set up your transformations as
>   follows:

```
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity(); 
 gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0); 
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity(); 
 gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0,
           0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
           0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

> It's important to note how the Projection
>   and ModelView transforms work
>   together.
>
> In this example, the Projection
>   transform sets up a 50.0-degree field
>   of view, with an aspect ratio of 1.0.
>   The zNear clipping plane is 3.0 units
>   in front of the eye, and the zFar
>   clipping plane is 7.0 units in front
>   of the eye. This leaves a Z volume
>   distance of 4.0 units, ample room for
>   a unit sphere.
>
> The ModelView transform sets the eye
>   position at (0.0, 0.0, 5.0), and the
>   look-at point is the origin in the
>   center of our unit sphere. Note that
>   the eye position is 5.0 units away
>   from the look at point. This is
>   important, because a distance of 5.0
>   units in front of the eye is in the
>   middle of the Z volume that the
>   Projection transform defines. If the
>   gluLookAt() call had placed the eye at
>   (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), it would produce a
>   distance of 1.0 to the origin. This
>   isn't long enough to include the
>   sphere in the view volume, and it
>   would be clipped by the zNear clipping
>   plane.
>
> Similarly, if you place the eye at
>   (0.0, 0.0, 10.0), the distance of 10.0
>   to the look at point will result in
>   the unit sphere being 10.0 units away
>   from the eye and far behind the zFar
>   clipping plane placed at 7.0 units.
>
> If this has confused you, read up on
>   transformations in the OpenGL red book
>   or OpenGL Specification. After you
>   understand object coordinate space,
>   eye coordinate space, and clip
>   coordinate space, the above should
>   become clear. Also, experiment with
>   small test programs. If you're having
>   trouble getting the correct transforms
>   in your main application project, it
>   can be educational to write a small
>   piece of code that tries to reproduce
>   the problem with simpler geometry.

Comment: I've actually already read that part of the FAQ and didn't find anything to help. The numbers I entered into the gluLookAt() matrix here are arbitrary. The cube is centered at (0, 0, -5.0) and has sides of length 1. When my program starts, I'm always looking directly at the front face, regardless of the coordinates in gluLookAt().

Comment: It worked!  That'll teach me not to leave out what I think is boilerplate code... One question though. I thought loadIdentity() only applied to the top of the stack. Since I pushed a matrix before calling it, shouldn't it have had no effect after popping the stack?

Comment: @Joel, I'll add to the answer.  Hang on.