# JOGL: Drawing spheres at specified position causes issues

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, glut, jogl

I am trying to draw spheres in a 3D OpenGL canvas with JOGL using the following GLUT-Method:

```
GLUT glut = new GLUT();
glut.glutSolidSphere(radius, stacks, slices);
```

The size is defined by the `radius`-attribute and the position with

```
gl.glTranslatef(posX, posY, posZ);
```

In my scenario, I am drawing 3 identical spheres with different x-coordinates. I expected to get 3 spheres with the same size and the same y- and z-coordinates, but instead I am getting this (I also applied some light and colour-settings but I don't think that this is related to the issue):

[image]

Not only the radius of the spheres has resulted differently, but also their z-position varies. The first sphere is drawn as expected, but the second and the third become smaller and they are positioned behind the previous ones on the z-axis.

I have no clue of what could have caused this behaviour... My idea is that it could have something to do with OpenGL-states..

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of research revealed the answer:

the method

```
gl.glTranslate(posX,posY,posZ);
```

shifts the matrix based on the position of the previous matrix, because both of them are multiplicated with each other, which causes those bizarre values.
The solution is reloading the identity in order to reset the matrix to the default state by calling the following method:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslate(posX,posY,posZ);
```

This is the result:

[image]

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737980/opengl-set-position-instead-of-translating)  helped me with finding the answer